# rows with highest 'column B' per grouped by 'column A'

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I want to get a single row per group (according to column A) and this row should be the one with the highest "B" value in that group. By the way (A,B) is unique if required. I write the following sql code, which does the job. I am wondering is there something more efficient? I prefer something pure SQL but I am going to use this in a stored procedure in SQL SERVER 2012.

```
DECLARE @mytab TABLE (A INT, B INT, C INT)
INSERT INTO @mytab ( A, B, C ) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @mytab ( A, B, C ) VALUES (1, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO @mytab ( A, B, C ) VALUES (1, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @mytab ( A, B, C ) VALUES (2, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO @mytab ( A, B, C ) VALUES (3, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @mytab ( A, B, C ) VALUES (3, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO @mytab ( A, B, C ) VALUES (3, 1, 3)
;WITH numbered AS 
(
SELECT *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B DESC)
FROM @mytab AS m
)
SELECT A, B, C
FROM numbered
WHERE rn=1
```

returns following

```
    A   B   C
    1   3   1
    2   2   2
    3   3   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my tests the following query performed 35% better using your test data x 100,000 rows.

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM @mytab mytab_outer
WHERE B = (SELECT MAX(B) FROM @mytab WHERE A = mytab_outer.A)
```

If you look at the execution plan, this wins out because for your query it spends all its time on the sort function (96%).

What drove me nuts about this question is that I thought your query would do better if I turned it into a temporary table and created a primary key for A and B (*you can create primary keys for table variables -- I forgot at the time*).  I made sure to run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` before I tested again.

The above query ran **75 times** faster, while your query had the same execution time as before.  It did not use the clustered index created by the primary key.  Even when I added and index for both column A and column B, it still did not help.  I tried using table hints, to no avail.

So from my tests, your method seems to be the least efficient way to do things, especially if there are indexes.

**EDIT**
So I figured out why the query with the window function was doing so bad.

If I remove the direction in the order by clause, then it uses the indexes I created, but of course the output is then wrong.  So if use a table variable the results of this query will always be bad because you can't control the direction the index is sorted.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the above query did much better, but your query had the same execution time'?  How is it much better and the same?

Comment: @GoatCO . . . This bothered me too.  I'm pretty sure it means "The above query did much better with a composite primary key, but your query had the same execution time".  (Once I understood that I upvoted the answer.)  As a rule, I would go with the `row_number()` approach.  In particular situations, other methods can be faster.

Comment: @GoatCo, please see my updated answer as I figured out why the performance was worse than my query, and why it is much worse than my query when I added the primary key.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to run some tests on some big tables today if I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery/cte is typically the best-performing solution to this problem.  Most alternatives would require a `JOIN`, and therefore do not perform as well.